# Trouble saving templates especially if there are more than a few lines in it

Tags: templates, ee5, memory

I have this weird problem where templates are sometimes saved and sometimes not. I would guess it has to do with a memory issue of some kind but I don't know where to look.

I run EE 5.3.2 fresh install on PHP 7.2

I don't get an error from EE but from the server. So maybe it's a server setting. But again, where to look? Please help me out.

This is the server error message I get in my browser:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /admin.php?/cp/design/template/edit/27 on this server.
www.websitename.nl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a Mod Security issue. If your web host has strict mod_sec rules doing some things in EE can trigger them.

I'd suggest making the error happen, making a note of the it happens, then look in your server logs to see if a rule is being triggered - if that's the case you may need to disable one or two specific rules. If you can't access mod_sec then ask your host to investigate and disable those rules (a good web host will do this for you!).

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your clear instructions, Bluedreamer. I will investigate and come back on this.

Comment: Looks like you were right. I found this in the logs:
[Fri Jul 03 14:34:57.094565 2020] [:error] [pid 4103211:tid 140705863268096] [client 77.61.6.85:60599] [client 77.61.6.85] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "<\\\\?(?!xml\\\\s)" at ARGS:template_data etc...